# Displaying an Business 2 or Notes field in Outlook contact card company wide?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013, outlook-2013

A manager in our organization wants a quick and easy way to see a person's extension number when he looks at the contact card from office (the small one that appears when you hover or a name not the full card) but does not want it as part of the normal office number. Looking inside of Active Directory I did not see any where to add an explicit extension and no place looked to be appropriate for that. As a test I added my extension to the "other" telephone number as well as the "Notes" fields and I can see those pop up in the full contact card information window on the Phone/Notes tab but I don't see them in the quick info window. What is the easiest/best way to get out extensions listed as an additional field?

Comment: Can the extension be displayed on the expanded contact card (hover, click the downward arrow) or it must be on the tiny card?

Comment: @sippybear Yes, that is where we are trying to show the info at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In AD Users and Computers, use the Attribute Editor to populate a field with the user's extension.

**Edit:** To enable Attribute Editor:

- Open AD Users and Computers
- Click View -> Advanced Features (make sure it is selected)
- Now "Attribute Editor" will be a tab when you select "Properties" on an AD User

Here's a couple attributes you may want to use:

**AD Attribute**     |     **Outlook Field**

- telephoneNumber  |   Business
- otherTelephone   |   Business 2  *(**recommended**)*
- facsimileTelephoneNumber    | Fax
- telephoneAssistant    |    Assistant
- homePhone    |    Home
- otherHomePhone    |    Home 2
- mobile    | Mobile
- pager    |    Pager

If you install the Office ADMX templates, you can customize which fields are displayed on the contact card. The templates are available here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178992.aspx

There is a TechNet article about customizing all sorts of features in Outlook 2013 via GPO. The portion specifically about Contact Cards is available here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631135.aspx#BKMK_ContactCards

The relevant GPO Path is here:

**User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Microsoft Office 2013\Contact Card\Contact Tab**

In this section there are options to customize label names and change what attributes are displayed.

Comment: Thanks for this, we will test it out and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have accepted this answer and awarded the bounty. I would up vote it but apparently I lost that ability when I put the bounty up.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it worked out :)